# Rendering 4000px + images

Tags: image, flutter

So currently I'm trying to render a large image for example:

I tried [CachedNetworkImageProvider](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) from pub_dev.

I also tried various different Providers with combination of Image widget. None of them worked.

The only widget that allows me to render the image is [photo_view](https://pub.dev/packages/photo_view#-readme-tab-) which renders the 4k image but has Zoomable feature that I don't want to have.

How can I remove this feature and fit with BoxFit?

Libraries tried to render the image:

- [extended_image](https://pub.dev/packages/extended_image)
- [image_ink_well](https://pub.dev/packages/image_ink_well)
- [flutter_advanced_networkimage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_advanced_networkimage)

Comment: Just looking at `photo_view`'s documentation it seems as though a work around to it zooming would be when you create the `PhotoView` you set its initial scale to 1.0, and max and min scale to 1.0 also stopping it from being able to zoom in for example: `PhotoView(imageProvider: AssetImage("assets/large-image.jpg"), initial Scale: 1.0, maxScale: 1.0, minScale: 1.0),`

Comment: @R.Duggan Yeah I'm not sure whats the move here... Is there any other widget that I can use to render large images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `PhotoView` you can disable the zoom functionality.

```dart
IgnorePointer( // The PhotoView widget thinks there's nothing happening
               // because you're catching any clicks that happen here.
  child: PhotoView(
    minScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.covered,
    maxScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.covered,
  ),
),
```

You can read more about the PhotoView class here: https://pub.dev/documentation/photo_view/latest/photo_view/PhotoView-class.html

Comment: I accepted this, setting both minScale and maxScale to covered, and wrapping the PhotoView widget with IgnorePointer works, that gets rid of the Zoomable options.

I also wrapped the image in a Card where I clipped with Anti-Aliasing